# any danger in using an html object as attribute "name" in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, dom, object

in linking javascript objects with html objects

```
// javascript element
var element = { tag:'input', name: 'email', value:null, dom: null,
   verifyFunc: function() {...}, postFunc: function() {...},
   rcdElement: some_element }

// lookup javascript element from dom
var doms = {};

// create html element for dom
var item = document.createElement(element.tag);
item.name = element.name;
...

// cross-link
doms[item] = element;
element.dom = item;

// using it in generic "onchange" trigger
function changeTrigger(e) {
  var el = doms[e.target];
  ....
};
```

are there any dangers lurking in this approach?

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like a bad Idea. However, without researching it more, I'm hesitant to say anything other than *it's probably a bad idea or "technique"*.

Comment: Why not just store a  reference to the object in a `data-` property?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - yes, I know what you mean.  my best thought so far is that, if the dom reference is a simple pointer/object type, then should be ok, but if evaluated, then could be problem.

Comment: @GGG - oops, too much sql programming lately - thanks

Comment: @GGG - `data-` you're right - good for (and limited to) text attribute values.  changed `element` to give it more life - includes functions and references to other objects as well, a much more complex situation than simple text value attributes

Comment: Try using [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: @ccyoung `data-` is just a way to ensure that a property assigned to a DOMNode object does *not* get interpreted as an attribute value... it is not limited to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object keys are strings.  So, when you try to use a DOM object as an object key, it will call `toString()` on the DOM object and use that as the key.  `toString()` on DOM objects returns non-unique things like this:

```
[object HTMLParagraphElement]
```

So, it won't cause an error, but it probably won't do what you want.  It would probably make more sense to use the object's ID as the key and generate a unique ID to put on the object if the object doesn't already have an id.

As best I can tell, any use of using an object as a key can also be done with the id as a key.

Comment: That was my hunch, but haven't found a way to reference that with a source yet. I think my [test code](http://jsbin.com/efuluk/) demonstrates that, I just don't have a reference to point authoritatively (yet).

Comment: I tested it out myself before writing my answer (had to use JSBin for the first time since jsFiddle is down) to see how it all works.  I knew that keys were strings, but had to test it myself to see how it worked when you tried to use an object as a key.

Comment: Keep in mind, I 100% agree; it sounds like we did the same thing to "validate" what we thought was right. I'm just looking for some spec that explains this I suppose "officially".

Comment: As I read the [EcmaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in section 11.1.5, it says a propertyName is an IdentifierName, a StringLiteral or a NumericLiteral.  Since there's no way to convert a DOM object to an IdentifierName or a NumericLiteral, the only option left is to call toString() to get a string.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm I'm putting this together correctly: [Section 11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=77) specifies *The production `PropertyName : StringLiteral` is evaluated as follows: 1. Return the [String Value] of the `StringLiteral.`*. In 8.6.2, (I think) it then calls [`Object.prototype.toString()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=45). In other words, [`console.log(el);` and `console.log(el.toString());` are equivalent](http://jsbin.com/ehesiz) if `el` if an HTML element?

Comment: [MDN on `Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString): *Every object has a `toString()` method that is **automatically called when the object is** to be represented as a text value or when an object is **referred to in a manner in which a string is expected**.* The bold is my own, but I think that sufficiently concludes the investigation (unless I've gotten something wrong).

Answer (score 1):

When I run this in Firefox 10:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var doms = {},
        item,
        element = { 
            tag: 'input', 
            name: 'email', 
            value: null,
            dom: null
        };

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        item = document.createElement(element.tag);
        item.name = element.name + i;
        document.body.appendChild(item);

        doms[item] = element;
    }

    console.log(doms);
};
```

I see the following in Firebug's console:

```
Object { [object HTMLInputElement]={...}}
```

Which expands to:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]   Object { tag="input", name="email", value=null, more...}

dom                         null

name                        "email"

tag                         "input"

value                       null
```

http://jsbin.com/efuluk/

Note, there's only one reference/object pair, not ten. I suspect you can't do this, and I would advise against it anyways (in lieu of a specific citation supporting my hunch).

Comment: great test!  if had different names might have worked.  as you noted, @jfriend's ecma script reference says identifier name is string or numeric literal, which explains everything